# Why @ssut/nestjs-sqs should be used in a service file instead of a controller?

Tags: controller, nestjs, amazon-sqs

I'm starting to work with [@ssut/nestjs-sqs](https://github.com/ssut/nestjs-sqs) and I'm a bit confused about how it works. 
By the documentation, you need to have this code in a provider:

```js
        @SqsMessageHandler(/** name: */ 'queueName', /** batch: */ false)
        public async handleMessage(message: AWS.SQS.Message) {  
         // Logic to handle the message
        }
```

I'll would like to have the message consumed in a controller and then I'll send the data to a provider. But if I try to had this method into a controller, I get

```
[SqsService] No metadata found for: <my_sqs_queue>
```

Why does the messageHandler method only works in a Service file and not in the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's due to how Nest's `DiscoveryService` works and [how the `SqsService` makes use of the `DiscoveryService`](https://github.com/ssut/nestjs-sqs/blob/master/lib/sqs.service.ts). There is a `Discover#providerMethodsWithMetaAtKey` method that **only** looks at providers, so when you add that decorator to a controller, the discovery service won't ever see it and the sqs service won't be able to act upon it.